# friendly url causes ajax to not get the correct url

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I converted the URL to user friendly, but the problem is, it caused my AJAX to not work properly: instead of returning JSON, it responds with `text/html; charset=utf-8`, any idea?

***localhost/Home/Ticket?tab=0***

**to**

***localhost/Home/Ticket/0***

**jquery Datatable**

```
self.$('#tblticket').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '/Home/Ticket/AjaxHandler',
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData){
     aoData.push( { "name": "sStatus", "value": status } );
 },
```

**Routers**

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "TicketRoute",
   url: "Ticket/{tab}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Ticket", action = "Index", tab = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Update 1**

If I change the router to this, it works, but the url will look like
***localhost/Home/Ticket/Index/0***. The router interferes with the ajax call, any idea? I want the url to look like this ***localhost/Home/Ticket/0*** and still be able to ajax call, I have no idea, what can be done?

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TicketRoute",
            url: "Ticket/Index/{tab}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Ticket", action = "Index", tab = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: In my opinion problem is with `"sAjaxSource": '/Home/Ticket/AjaxHandler',` but you can easy check what's going on using network tab in FireBug

Comment: Is the source URL correct? should'nt it be `Home/Ticket/0` ?

Comment: The AjaxHandler is to call the httpget in code behind, if without urlfriendlylines, it work find, but after I change it, it not work properly as it keep return as text/html, I had debug before and after of url friendliness, both pass the same, but the content type is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my MVC4 version I did the following:

1. Created a method in my controller that DataTables can access

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetRecords(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
   {
       #region ViewModel Binding with TotalRecords count, pagination and search
       List<vm_DataTable_TableName> model;
       int totalRecords = 0;
       using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
       {
           model = Mapper.Map(db.GetRecords(), new List<vm_DataTable_TableName>()); //Using AutoMapper for viewmodel bindings
           totalRecords = model.Count();
       }
       #endregion

       #region Filtration/Pagination
       var filtered = ***Filter depending on your needs***

       var displayed = filtered.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
       #endregion

       #region Convert Result to String Array for JSON Conversion/Trim excess white space to reduce size of result
       IEnumerable<string[]> result = new List<string[]>();
       result = displayed
                .Select(s => new string[] {
                   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(s.ID))) ? s.ID.ToString().Trim() : string.Empty,
                   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.val_1)) ? s.val_1.Trim() : string.Empty,
                   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.val_2)) ? s.val_2.Trim() : string.Empty,
                   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.val_3)) ? s.val_3.Trim() : string.Empty
                });
       #endregion

       return Json(new
       {
           sEcho = param.sEcho,
           iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
           iTotalDisplayRecords = filtered.Count(),
           aaData = result
       },
       JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
2. In the jQuery DataTables initialisation:

   ```
   $('#tblticket').dataTable({
       "bDestroy": true,
       "bServerSide": true,
       "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Content("~/Home/Ticket/GetRecords")', //Server inserted url
       "fnServerData": function Data(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
           $.ajax({
               "dataType": "json",
               "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               "type": "GET",
               "url": sSource,
               "data": aoData,
               "success":
                   function (msg) {
                       //Whatever other actions you want to do with the data
                       fnCallback(msg);
                   },
               "failure":
                   function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                       alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                   }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

'@Url.Content("")' is also friendly when using MVC Areas.

[These](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part) series of articles helped me a lot when i first started using this plugin.

Comment: url.content will not work at external script, anywhere, thanks for the info :)

Comment: You put the above code as inline on your view for the server code to work. Either that or create a function call to pass the relative path into the ajax source that way (if I'm reading the comment right).